# EditText Background

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a picture of small size and want to set the background to EditText. Can I make a picture dragged on only one axis, such that x, without loss of quality

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can turn it into a 9-patch image and define stretchable regions on an image.
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html